# Is it possible to prevent python from termination until block ends?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, atomic

Basically, I'm curious if it's possible to execute a block of python code "atomically" without being interrupted by a signal.

For instance, I want to perform operations in a loop, let's say:

```
for i in range(100):
    do_stuff(1)
    do_stuff(2)
    do_stuff(3)
```

But I want to finish all of three `do_stuff(1)`, `do_stuff(2)`, `do_stuff(3)` if `do_stuff(1)` **managed to start**. Script should ignore CTRL+C, finish these three instructions and then terminate if SIGINT happened. All of 100 iterations does not have to be executed.

I believe it could be done with a custom signal handler

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    # wait for the loop iteration finish and exit
```

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```

threads and synchronization but I have no idea how to implement it.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is, can it be done nicely? With some kind of a context manager, for example?

```
for i in range(100):
    with atomic_execution():
        do_stuff(1)
        do_stuff(2)
        do_stuff(3)
```

Edit: in the meantime I created this:

```
import threading
import sys
import signal


class atomic_execution:
    started = 0
    execution_in_progress = threading.Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        atomic_execution.execution_in_progress.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        atomic_execution.execution_in_progress.release()


def handler(signum, frame):
  atomic_execution.execution_in_progress.acquire()
  sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

while True:
  with atomic_execution():
    print(1)
    print(2)
    print(3)
```

I am not sure if it's good, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic idea:

```
import signal
import time

stop = False

def sighandler(*unused):
    global stop
    print('signal caught')
    stop = True

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print('a')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('b')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('c')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print()
        if stop:
            print('STOP')
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sighandler)
    main()
```

I think it is not difficult to make an context manager for this purpose:

on enter:

- save the current signal handler
- install own handler setting a flag like in the example above

on exit:

- restore the original signal handler
- exit if the flag was set

But I do not like the idea, because you want to install the handler once before the loop and test the flag many times at each iteration.

Comment: I believe that there's no way to avoid testing the flag. 
It could also use `Lock`s or `Condition`s just like I did in the edited answer but I don't know if it's for the better.

Comment: @asikorski Either the kernel blocks the signal for you - see low level Linux/Unix call `sigprocmask` which blocks/unblocks signals - or you need some kind of flag (or similar synchronisation mechanism). The latter is simpler and more portable.